# Using jQuery BlockUI plugin upon page navigation (unload event)

Tags: jquery, blockui, onunload, jquery-blockui

[jQuery BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#options) plugin has a very cool feature of attaching itself to every AJAX call with simple code:

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

Can I use similar approach to display blockUI overlay on each navigation, like clicking any link etc.?

I think, this should be done using `unload` event, but I failed with this.

```
$(window).on('unload', function()
{
    $.blockUI;
});
```

Upon navigation blockUI overlay does not appears (I don't care about hiding it, because new loaded page won't have it).

I can even:

```
$(window).on('unload', function()
{
    console.log('$.blockUI;');
    $.blockUI;
    console.log('Bye!');
});
```

and I clearly see both `$.blockUI;` and `Bye!` messages in console, but no sign of blockUI overlay.

I've read that many browsers blocks displaying `alert()`'s in `unload`. Does it also covers blockUI? It shouldn't as it is just a bunch of divs or other DOM elements plus some styling?

Tested in Chrome 27, Internet Explorer 10 and Firefox 21. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Two or three years ago, in an old project, I manage to achieve above mentioned functionality, but it was done there purely by biding blockUI showup to particular buttons and menu items. I would like to avoid this as much as possible and make it globally, just as with AJAX calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two problems. I think the first problem is that you have to call the function `$.blockUI()` to produce the desired result.

The second problem is that the event seems to be too late. Consider `beforeunload` event:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function()
{
    $.blockUI();
});
```

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/straeger/gxzbE/1/) which uses the `beforeunload` event, and it works very well.

Comment: You're right in both. Thanks for a very good (yet simple! :]) and quick answers.

Comment: There's [another problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424828/browser-doesnt-display-images-in-objects-shown-in-beforeunload-event), but I split it into separate question. Maybe you can help with that too?